# L2TP/IPSec not working in LUBUNTU 20.4

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, vpn, l2tp

I am trying to connect to my official vpn but it is not working. I am sharing some syslog and debug log. Please help

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog

May  1 00:22:32 luser NetworkManager[440]: <info>  [1651378952.6564] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" name="OfficeVPN" pid=933 uid=1000 result="success"                                                                                                               
May  1 00:22:32 luser NetworkManager[440]: <info>  [1651378952.6941] vpn-connection[0x55f43ce52330,7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726,"OfficeVPN",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 26582                                                                                  
May  1 00:22:32 luser NetworkManager[440]: <info>  [1651378952.7817] vpn-connection[0x55f43ce52330,7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726,"OfficeVPN",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection                                                                       
May  1 00:22:32 luser NetworkManager[440]: <info>  [1651378952.8443] vpn-connection[0x55f43ce52330,7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726,"OfficeVPN",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received                                                                 
May  1 00:22:32 luser NetworkManager[26593]: Redirecting to: systemctl restart ipsec.service                                          
May  1 00:22:32 luser systemd[1]: Stopping Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Protocol Daemon for IPsec...                                   
May  1 00:22:32 luser whack[26597]: 002 shutting down
May  1 00:22:33 luser ipsec[26603]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:33 luser libipsecconf[26603]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:33 luser systemd[1]: ipsec.service: Succeeded.
May  1 00:22:33 luser systemd[1]: Stopped Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Protocol Daemon for IPsec.
May  1 00:22:33 luser systemd[1]: Starting Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Protocol Daemon for IPsec...
May  1 00:22:33 luser addconn[26607]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:33 luser libipsecconf[26607]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:33 luser _stackmanager[26610]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:33 luser libipsecconf[26610]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:33 luser _stackmanager[26615]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:33 luser libipsecconf[26615]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:34 luser ipsec[26868]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:34 luser libipsecconf[26868]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:34 luser ipsec[26866]: nflog ipsec capture disabled
May  1 00:22:34 luser systemd[1]: Started Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Protocol Daemon for IPsec.
May  1 00:22:34 luser libipsecconf[26887]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 listening for IKE messages
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 Kernel supports NIC esp-hw-offload
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 adding interface wlp3s0/wlp3s0 (esp-hw-offload=no) 192.168.1.43:500
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 adding interface wlp3s0/wlp3s0 192.168.1.43:4500
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 Kernel supports NIC esp-hw-offload
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 adding interface lo/lo (esp-hw-offload=no) 127.0.0.1:500
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 adding interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1:4500
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 Kernel supports NIC esp-hw-offload
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 adding interface lo/lo (esp-hw-offload=no) ::1:500
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.secrets"
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26884]: 002 loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.nm-l2tp.secrets"
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26890]: debugging mode enabled
May  1 00:22:34 luser NetworkManager[26890]: end of file /run/nm-l2tp-7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726/ipsec.conf
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: Loading conn 7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: starter: left is KH_DEFAULTROUTE
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" modecfgdns=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" modecfgdomains=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" modecfgbanner=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" mark=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" mark-in=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" mark-out=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" vti_iface=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" redirect-to=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" accept-redirect-to=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" esp=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" ike=<unset>
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: opening file: /run/nm-l2tp-7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726/ipsec.conf
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: loading named conns: 7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 1, has_peer = 1
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: seeking_src = 0, seeking_gateway = 1, has_dst = 1
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: dst  via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 src  table 254
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: set nexthop: 192.168.1.1
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: dst 192.168.1.0 via  dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.1.43 table 254
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: dst 127.0.0.0 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: dst 127.0.0.0 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: dst 127.0.0.1 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: dst 127.255.255.255 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: dst 192.168.1.0 via  dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.1.43 table 255 (ignored)
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: dst 192.168.1.43 via  dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.1.43 table 255 (ignored)
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: dst 192.168.1.255 via  dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.1.43 table 255 (ignored)
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 0, has_peer = 1
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 0, has_dst = 1
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: dst 192.168.1.1 via  dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.1.43 table 254
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: set addr: 192.168.1.43
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26890]: seeking_src = 0, seeking_gateway = 0, has_peer = 1
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26892]: 031 "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726": cannot initiate connection with narrowing=no and (kind=CK_TEMPLATE)
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[26892]: 036 failed to initiate 7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726
May  1 00:22:35 luser nm-l2tp-service[26582]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[440]: <info>  [1651378955.2928] vpn-connection[0x55f43ce52330,7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726,"OfficeVPN",0]: VPN service disappeared
May  1 00:22:35 luser NetworkManager[440]: <warn>  [1651378955.3092] vpn-connection[0x55f43ce52330,7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726,"OfficeVPN",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
May  1 00:23:33 luser PackageKit: daemon quit
May  1 00:23:33 luser systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
```

and

```
sudo /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-l2tp-service --debug
[sudo] password for luser: 

nm-l2tp[39145] <debug> nm-l2tp-service (version 1.20.0) starting...
nm-l2tp[39145] <debug>  uses default --bus-name "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp"
nm-l2tp[39145] <info>  ipsec enable flag: yes
ipv6
        address-data : []
        dns : []
        dns-search : []
        ip6-privacy : 0
        method : 'auto'
        route-data : []

ipv4
        address-data : []
        dns : []
        dns-search : []
        method : 'auto'
        route-data : []

proxy

connection
        autoconnect : false
        id : 'OfficeVPN'
        permissions : ['user:luser:']
        type : 'vpn'
        uuid : 'UUID'

vpn
        data : {'ephemeral-port': 'yes', 'gateway': 'gateway', 'ipsec-enabled': 'yes', 'ipsec-forceencaps': 'yes', 'ipsec-ikev2': 'yes', 'ipsec-ipcomp': 'yes', 'machine-auth-type': 'psk', 'mru': '1400', 'mtu': '1400', 'password-flags': '0', 'user': 'vpnuser', 'user-auth-type': 'password'}
        secrets : {'ipsec-psk': 'presharedkey', 'password': 'password'}
        service-type : 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp'

nm-l2tp[39145] <info>  starting ipsec
Redirecting to: systemctl restart ipsec.service
002 listening for IKE messages
002 forgetting secrets
002 loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.secrets"
002 loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.nm-l2tp.secrets"
opening file: /run/nm-l2tp-7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726/ipsec.conf
debugging mode enabled
end of file /run/nm-l2tp-7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726/ipsec.conf
Loading conn 7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726
starter: left is KH_DEFAULTROUTE
loading named conns: 7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726
seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 1, has_peer = 1
seeking_src = 0, seeking_gateway = 1, has_dst = 1
dst  via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 src  table 254
set nexthop: 192.168.1.1
dst 192.168.1.0 via  dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.1.43 table 254
dst 127.0.0.0 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
dst 127.0.0.0 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
dst 127.0.0.1 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
dst 127.255.255.255 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
dst 192.168.1.0 via  dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.1.43 table 255 (ignored)
dst 192.168.1.43 via  dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.1.43 table 255 (ignored)
dst 192.168.1.255 via  dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.1.43 table 255 (ignored)

seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 0, has_peer = 1
seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 0, has_dst = 1
dst 192.168.1.1 via  dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.1.43 table 254
set addr: 192.168.1.43

seeking_src = 0, seeking_gateway = 0, has_peer = 1
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" modecfgdns=<unset>
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" modecfgdomains=<unset>
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" modecfgbanner=<unset>
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" mark=<unset>
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" mark-in=<unset>
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" mark-out=<unset>
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" vti_iface=<unset>
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" redirect-to=<unset>
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" accept-redirect-to=<unset>
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" esp=<unset>
conn: "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726" ike=<unset>
002 added connection description "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726"
nm-l2tp[39145] <info>  Spawned ipsec auto --up script with PID 39454.
031 "7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726": cannot initiate connection with narrowing=no and (kind=CK_TEMPLATE)
036 failed to initiate 7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726
nm-l2tp[39145] <warn>  Could not establish IPsec tunnel.

(nm-l2tp-service:39145): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 00:58:46.781: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
```

Comment: try stopping the system xl2tpd service, see:
https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp#unable-to-establish-l2tp-connection-without-udp-source-port-1701

Answer (score 1):

As you are using network-manager-l2tp 1.20.0 from the [nm-l2tp PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp), the fix is to upgrade to version 1.20.4 :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade network-manager-l2tp
```

You shouldn't need to stop the system xl2tpd for this issue anymore, the issue was fixed with the following commit in the source code :

https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp/commit/a2387d7111e52c1854db8dc557ae2483e8551824

Comment: thanks for your answer. after  upgrading the network-manager-l2tp  still no luck

Comment: Do you still get the `cannot initiate connection with narrowing=no and (kind=CK_TEMPLATE)` error or a different error? That same error you were getting was described on https://swan.libreswan.narkive.com/T1UhZLLB/upgrade-to-3-18-broke-roadwarrior-connection . Issue `sudo cat
/run/nm-l2tp-7aa5b8a6-5c38-4e1e-a194-8cf1c6881726/ipsec.conf` and see if `leftprotoport=udp/%any` is still in there.